# Why is my Angular default app's app.component.scss empty?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Just started to learn Angular

Ran `ng new angular-app --style=scss --skip-tests=true` from the terminal.
File structure is provisioned as expected, but to my surprise all styling is located within a `<style>` tag in my app.component.html file, and my app.component.scss file is desperately empty.

I'm not an expert, but always been told it was not good practice at all. Why would Angular developers implement such behavior then? Is that a bug?

Comment: Not sure what is the question,but i think you are over thinking. The  startup template generated by angular has `style.scss` which  will be a global styles sheet   and also individual component `.scss` files for each component when created through cli ( is empty cause the idea is to give you a startup template). At production angular bundles all the files `ng build --prod`.The term `it was not good practice at all` is not applicable here because the code you write is well structured is easy to maintain and removed unwanted spaces and also helps you to scope the styles to a particular component

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can use styles in your application and using `<style>` is one way, that could not be the optimal way that you are expecting, but this default template is just a template to give some information about Angular. When you develop the application you can use your preferred way to style the application. And this is not a **BUG**

Answer (score 0):

No It's not a bug Each time you generate a new component, you have your **component.scss** By default, Angular is able to perform an emulated Shadow **DOM**

There are two main advantages with this technique:

1. These **CSS** properties will be loaded only if the component is used in the rendered page. (better performance)
2. The **CSS** is scoped and simplified. (better productivity)

And Also read

Global **CSS** is easy to use: just insert some properties in **styles.scss** and it will always be present in each component.